# Redirecting HTTP Requests

Tags: c++, linux, http

I am working on creating plug-and-play software for cameras behind a firewall. To do that, the camera has a command that tells it to connect to a server of mine (over http), in which I can talk to it in http.

I need to export this connection to users, so that when I get http requests, I forward them directly to the camera, and forward the responses back to the user.

My initial idea was just to use tcp - get the camera connection using tcp, and continuously wait for user connections. When I get a user connection - I forward everything from it to the camera, and from the camera to it. In other words - plain old port redirection.

The problem begins when the user needs to have several active connections to the camera. I hoped this would not be an issue - but I have found out (or at least that's what I think happens) that browsers actually open several connections to the same site to download files.

Now I have no choice but to write code that actually reads the http request, dispatches it to the camera, waits for the camera's response, and sends it back. 
That is the only way to allow multiple connections to the same camera using just one connection (as far as I can see).

My question is - is there any existing code to do this? Libraries? Software? Or is there any better way to do what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: Well, apparently I was wrong about the browser creating several connections to the server. What actually happens is that the server returns HTTP 1.0 responses, and as I have found out, HTTP 1.0 allows a single request (and response) per connection. What I was seeing is the browser just leaving the used connection it has opened earlier open, and opening a new one for a new request.

However, I still had to do HTTP message forwarding myself (I only implemented "text/html", "text/plain" and some other custom content type which is used by the camera). So for instance, the browser doesn't show pictures at all. So if anyone knows about any code that does http message forwarding (or an application that does it), I would love to hear it.

As a side note - I have checked the proxy feature of httpd (apache). Not only is it very complicated, it also seems to allow only one proxy connection on the machine. So I abandoned that direction and implemented basic forwarding myself.

Thanks

Comment: The functionality you're looking for is normally provided by a HTTP proxy server. There are lots of open source projects.. Maybe you find one which can be customized easily?

Comment: Could you give more information? Which side is initiating the connection; is your objective to connect to the camera from the outside, or to have the camera connect to something else?

Comment: I have the server address hard wired to the camera, and then it connects back to me when it is connected to the user's LAN (over http). Then I need to accept user connections from the outside and let them access the camera (using the connection I have).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: 1) on your firewall you have a rule saying: everything coming in <external_ip>:<port> forward to <camera_ip>:<port> 2) you can access the camera over http and if so 3) you can have multiple internal clients (i.e. multiple browsers) connected to the camera without problems (so no firewall/router) but it doesn't work when clients connect from the outside (through the firewall/router)?

Comment: Well, I actually do the forwarding myself (in a custom program). It might as well have been a port forward, but the camera needs someone to send it an ack when it first connects (some http request). Afterwards I completely forward everything on the port. I can access the camera (only) over http since the connection is in http. And I think it's a yes about 3) as well, but the server and camera are not in the same network - so only browsers in that network would work (which don't know the camera's ip), but definitely external browsers don't work (since they need multiple concurrent connections).

Comment: Not clear. Tell us the correct flow you expect. The client HTTP connects to your server and your server HTTP connects to the camera? If this is correct then you need a reverse proxy on your server. Apache httpd does it perfectly. It's not clear how the server connects to the camera because if the firewall does NAT and it's not configured to port forward external TCP/80 port to the camera you cannot do it this way. In this case you may need a tunnel solution on the camera / server side (openvpn it's very ok), then you need the reverse proxy on the server as well.

Comment: The flow is: 1. Camera connects to server (some HTTP request). 2. Server answers with a bogus answer, and the direction is switched, so that now the camera is the http-server and the server is the http-client. 3. Forward the HTTP connection (as if the camera is the server). The server doesn't connect to the camera - that's the point of plug and play. The camera connects to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Web servers embeded in Cameras are not able to scale so you should rather query the camera, put the images in a cache and then push the latest images to each client (preferably using presistent HTTP 1.1 connections).

How to do it depends on your latency needs (delay between refreshes) and how many clients will join the game.

If sounds like a job for G-WAN (a fast server with C, C++, D, Java, and Objective-C/C++ scripts to generate dynamic contents), but I might be partial since I am part of the project.